# python dictionary nested ques for printing max value with key

Tags: python

We represent scores of batsmen across a sequence of matches in a two level dictionary as follows:

{'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}

Each match is identified by a string, as is each player.  The scores are all integers.  The names associated with the matches are not fixed (here they are 'match1','match2','match3'), nor are the names of the players.  A player need not have a score recorded in all matches

Define a Python function "orangecap(d)" that reads a dictionary d of this form and identifies the player with the highest total score.  Your function should return a pair (playername,topscore) where playername is a string, the name of the player with the highest score, and topscore is an integer, the total score of playername.

The input will be such that there are never any ties for highest total score.

For instance:

> > > orangecap({'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}})
> > >       ('player3', 100)

Comment: Hello, please read this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to operate on nested dictionary in python 3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444903/how-to-operate-on-nested-dictionary-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the main dict and, inside each dict, iterate over each player

```
def best(dico_match):
    dico_player = dict()
    best_player = None
    top_score = 0

    for match,players in dico_match.items():
        for player,score in players.items():
            if player in dico_player:
                dico_player[player] += score
            else:
                dico_player[player] = score
            if dico_player[player] > top_score:
                top_score = dico_player[player]
                best_player = player
    return best_player,top_score
print(best({'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42},
            'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}}))
```