# How to operate on nested dictionary in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, nested

I am stuck with this question, can you solve the challenge? Here we go!

We represent scores of players across a sequence of matches in a two level dictionary as follows:

```
{'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}}
```

Each match is identified by a string, as is each player.  The scores are all integers.  The names associated with the matches are not fixed (here they are 'match1','match2','match3'), nor are the names of the players.  A player need not have a score recorded in all matches.

Define a Python function `orangecap(d)` that reads a dictionary d of this form and identifies the player with the highest total score.  Your function should return a pair (playername,topscore) where playername is a string, the name of the player with the highest score, and topscore is an integer, the total score of playername.

The input will be such that there are never any ties for highest total score.

For instance:

```
>>> orangecap({'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}})
('player3', 100)

>>> orangecap({'test1':{'Ashwin':84, 'Kohli':120}, 'test2':{'ashwin':59, 'Pujara':42}})
('Kohli', 120)
```

Comment: *challenge?* Is this a (running) programming contest?

Comment: Please be more specific about the issue you are facing. We will not solve the problem for you.

Comment: I just stumbled upon multiple instances of this question on stackoverflow. Is something happening?

Comment: Appears to be an assignment or something o.0 ?

Answer (score 3):

with `pandas` it's really easy:

```
In [78]: d
Out[78]: 
{'match1': {'player1': 57, 'player2': 38},
 'match2': {'player1': 42, 'player3': 9},
 'match3': {'player2': 41, 'player3': 91, 'player4': 63}}

In [79]: pd.DataFrame(d).sum(axis=1).idxmax()
Out[79]: 'player3'

In [80]: pd.DataFrame(d).sum(axis=1).max()
Out[80]: 100.0
```

First convert it to a DataFrame, then sum over the columns, and find the max :)

Comment: How do you put ipython code here as an answer? showing the `In[]` and `Out[]` stuff?

Comment: I've found that using anaconda and spyder works the best for answering stack overflow questions. Then you can "copy (raw text)" from the ipython console in spyder3

Comment: It looks nicer and cooler as an answer :) I will take a look at spyder3,thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga for example on windows that might not be so trivial

Comment: @SebastianWozny ah, yes. cmd.exe is a joke. I would suggest finding a terminal emulator that *doesn't suck*, but that might not be so trivial for Windows.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga omg, I get it now. xD  I run my ipython on jupyter notebook, not sure if I can also copy paste from there? I see how you would 'just copy it from the terminal' :D I thought people had a way of directly copy and pasting from a jupyter notebook

Comment: @AsheKetchum those are almost certainly coming from some ipython terminal session.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, that explains a lot lol. I was trying all sorts of methods to import from web browser notebook. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use a running counter to count the scores first:

```
from collections import Counter

def orangecap(d):
    total = Counter()
    for match_result in d.values():
        total.update(match_result)
    return total.most_common(1)[0]
```

Here [`Counter.update(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=most_common#collections.Counter.update) will increment the counters for the players mentioned. [`Counter.most_common(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=most_common#collections.Counter.most_common) specifies we want the first most common element. This will return a list and we pick the first tuple.

```
>>> orangecap(d)
('player3', 100)
```

Comment: thats perfect Willem!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using Willem Van Onsem answer, but if you don't want to import then here is an alternative.

```
data = {
    'match1': {
        'player1': 57,
        'player2': 38},
    'match2': {
        'player3': 9,
        'player1': 42},
    'match3': {
        'player2': 41,
        'player4': 63,
        'player3': 91}
    }


def orangecap(data):
    totals = {}
    for d in data.values():
        for k, v in d.items():
            totals[k] = totals.setdefault(k, 0) + v

    return max(totals.items(), key = lambda t:t[1])

>>> orangecap(data)
('player3', 100)
```

Comment: I think op wants the total score of that player :P

Comment: Ah, failed to see total. Thanks

Comment: Its one of the best of the answers. Thanks a lot. actually theres a need to calculate the total scores as the output. in this case the output should be 91+9 from match3 and match 2. So the result should be 100. but its showing 91. can you make an edit for that?

Comment: I've already edited my answer. My previous answer didn't total the scores for each player then find the max.

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator

def orangecap(d):
    players = {}    
    for dict in d.values():
        for player in dict:
            if player in players:
               players[player] += dict[player]
            else:
               players[player] = dict[player]

    scores = sorted(players.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
    return scores[0]

#Credits to  Willem Van Onsem for his various suggestions
```

Comment: you can try `collections.defaultdict`:)

Comment: Furthermore `sorted(..)` does **not work inline** (especially since dictionaries have no order) and you do not have to sort anyway: you can use `max` for that.

Comment: Uhh well spotted @WillemVanOnsem, this code will never work. You mean __inplace__ rather than __inline__ though. :( You should fix the code or you will get downvoted.

Comment: @SebastianWozny: yeah indeed (English is not my native language).

Comment: my apologies, I thought I wrote something else :P

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so max would return the key associated with the largest value?

Comment: @AsheKetchum: you need to sort `reverse=True` and furthermore you can use `player in `players` instead of `.keys()` (which will improve efficiency).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you so much for the fixes! Is it good now?

Comment: @AsheKetchum: no. After the `sorted(..)` players is a **list of tuples**. So you should `return players[0]` (sorry).

Comment: @AsheKetchum: and another one: you set `players[player] = 0` (but it should be `dict[player]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think that's ok? I kept track of the total scores in the dictionary `players`. It was a bit confusing since I originally overwrote `players`. Changed the resulting list of tuples to `scores` now.

Comment: @AsheKetchum: but in the case `player` is not in `players` it means you want to **add** the player for the first time (with its score for the first match). Now your algorithm pretends that that player scored 0 on his/her first match.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I see what you are saying, you are correct :) Thanks again for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

Some code golfing with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter

v = reduce(lambda x, y: x.update(y) or x, d.values(), Counter()).most_common(1)[0])
print(v)
# ('player3', 100)
```